# php's ssh2 extension installation on RHEL8 with php 7.4

Tags: php, rhel8

I have installed php7.4 via RHEL8's Default Stream using dnf.
I want to install the php's ssh2 module.

How do I install Pyrus (Pear2 Package Manager) on RHEL8 with php7.4?

When I tried: `php pyrus.phar`
I got the error message in command prompt: Could not open input file: pyrus.phar

I used:

```
updatedb 
locate pyrus
```

Got nothing

So, what is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to install php's ssh2 extension via Pyrus but I was having trouble with Pyrus. Therefore, I tried it without Pyrus. I preferred yum or dnf installation throughout. But, it was not possible for some. The following are how I have installed ssh2:

```
yum install make gcc php-devel php-pear
```

libssh2 package (ssh2 package needs it) installed by downloading the file https://libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.10.0.tar.gz into an appropriate folder.
Then, I entered the following commands:

```
tar -zxvf libssh2-1.10.0.tar.gz
cd libssh2-1.10.0
./configure
make
make install
```

ssh2 package installed by downloading the file https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-1.3.1.tgz into an appropriate folder.
Then, I entered the following commands:

```
tar -zxvf ssh2-1.3.1.tgz
cd ssh2-1.3.1
phpize
./configure
make
make test
make install
```

Then I entered the following entry into /etc/php.ini: `extension=ssh2.so`

After that, I restarted php by: `systemctl restart php-fpm`

And now, php's ssh2 extension has been successfully installed.

Comment: I followed this same process on RHEL8 with php 8.0.15 with success!

Answer (score 0):

In my first attempt when running `./compile` on redhat 8 and PHP 7.2
i got the following errors :

```
configure: ERROR: No openssl crypto library found!  
No libgcrypt crypto library found!  
No mbedtls crypto library found!  
No wincng crypto library found!
```

After installing `mbedtls` + `openssl-devel` it worked !